# Why does Laravel environment change on different networks?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

When at work, Laravel detects that I am on a local environment correctly, based on my machine's network name. When I take my work home with me and pop open the laptop Laravel thinks I'm on production.

Nothing changes apart from I'm connected to a different Wi-Fi network.

Why?

Comment: Are you sure it's the network? I didn't know Laravel could do that. Maybe check your config files, or your .env file? Are you using Homestead, or the dev server?

Comment: That's the only thing I can think of, which I think is doubtful, that's why I'm asking the question :)
I'm running on `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 4.2 you can set the environment in bootstrap/start.php, in an array where different environments can be defined (local, staging, etc), by using your hostname or ip.

Here's an example:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('localhost', '127.0.0.1',  'Jack-PC', 'homestead'),

));
```

The default environment is production, so in your case your pc's name is not present in this array and so it defaults to production.

Comment: Yes, I have the environments defined.

I'm using the same laptop, at work and at home, so the network name of the laptop doesn't change.